# register a variable in all controllers

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller

I want to register a variable that will be available in all Controllers.

```
class testController extends Zend_Controller_Action{

   public function testAction(){
      echo $this->testVar;
   }
...
```

How and Where ,can I set the content of this variable so I can access it in every controller?

Comment: I would be better if you create a custom parent controller class and extent it in your controllers

Comment: You can use Session to store that variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Default_Controller extends Custom_Controller_Abstract
{
    public function testAction()
    {
        $this->content = 'Test';
    }
}

class Index_Controller extends Custom_Controller_Abstract
{
    public function testAction()
    {
        echo $this->content;
    }
}

class Custom_Controller_Abstract extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public $content;
    public function __construct(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract $response, array $invokeArgs = array)
    {       
        parent::__construct($request, $response,$invokeArgs);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just Declare that variable in /public/index.php.
    All the action starts from index.php so You can use it as a global variable if U declare in index.php